# AWS IAM customized policy at instance level for EC2 doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, policy

Created an AWS IAM policy for a user to give permission for only stopping and starting instance but if I give a particular instance ARN resource then it doesn’t work. Default EC2 Read only permission has been given to the user to describe EC2 instances and on top of that added customized sample policy as follows:

**Sample policy:**

```
  {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:StopInstances",
                    "ec2:RunInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "*"
```

> **This works**

```
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account id>:instance/<instance id>"  
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account id>:instance/*" 
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<region>::instance/*"
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:::instance/*"
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:::*"
```

> **These doesn’t work**

```
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Edited on 23rd January (To Show what exactly I have done)**

**Objective:** Start and stop instance permission on a single EC2 instance to a user.

Tested different combo policies but none of them worked except `"Resource": "*"`:

**Logged in:** admin_user (Full access)

Created an instance as follows:

1. **Region:** Oregon
2. **Availability zone:** us-west-2c
3. **Instance Id:** i-xxx3dxxx32xxxxxxe
4. **Owner:** xxx23xxx11

**Created a user:** testec2_user

Permissions given to the user:

1. EC2 read only (available policy)
2. Customized policy to permit only stop and start i-xxx38xxx32xx45 instance as follows:

   ```
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Action": [
               "ec2:Describe*",
               "ec2:RunInstances"
           ],
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Resource": "*"
       },
       {
           "Action": [
               "ec2:StopInstances",
               "ec2:StartInstances"
           ],
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2c:xxx23xxx11:instance/i-xxx3dxxx32xxxxxxe"
       }
           ] }
   ```

Logged in as `testec2_user` and tried starting up the stopped instance and received following error:

```
You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message
```

I have a plan for decoding the message received using `sts decode authorization message` of AWS.

Answer (score 4):

**DescribeInstances** does not support resource-level permissions. (See [Unsupported Resource-Level Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions)).

> If an Amazon EC2 API action does not support resource-level
>   permissions, you can grant users permission to use the action, but you
>   have to specify a * for the resource element of your policy statement.
>
> [Read more](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html)

So, you could re-write your policy as:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:instance/<instance-id>"
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT**

**RunInstances** needs access to several resource types besides *Instance* (Such as *Image*, *Key pair*, *Network interface*, *Placement group*, *Security group*, *Snapshot*, *Subnet* and *Volume*) and accepts a specific ARN format for each resource type. So, `arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account id>:instance/*` would not be enough and you'll get an `UnauthorizedOperation` error. The **"Resource"** element should either be:

```
"Resource": "*"
```

Which is the easiest way, or:

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:instance/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:<region>::image/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:key-pair/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:network-interface/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:placement-group/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:security-group/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:<region>::snapshot/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:subnet/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:volume/*"
]
```

Which is more complex but provides fine-grained control on each resource. For example, you can allow **RunInstances** execution for a specific EC2 image ID or subnet ID only. For more details, see the `RunInstances` section [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#instance).

**Additional note on PassRole Permission**

When executing **RunInstances**, if the EC2 instance should include an instance profile, the user who launches the EC2 instance must also have the IAM `PassRole` permission in order to associate a role with the instance during launch. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        ...
        {
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/<role-name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

This way, you make sure that a user doesn't pass a role to an EC2 instance where the role has more permissions than you want the user to have.

For more info on granting permission to launch EC2 instances with IAM roles, see [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/granting-permission-to-launch-ec2-instances-with-iam-roles-passrole-permission/) AWS blog article.

Comment: I tried all possible solution but instance level permission is not working. I have tried policy without Describe because Describe is available on EC2 Read Only policy (assigned to user). However, kept stop, start and run instances permission at a resource level but still permission issue persist for the user. How does `"Resource": "*"` works and not `"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account id>:instance/<instance id>"` for stop, start and run instances actions.

Comment: Seems like `RunInstances` does not accept an ARN of the format `arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account id>:instance/<instance id>`. It has to be `arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account id>:instance/*`. I have updated my answer accordingly. For more details, see the `RunInstances` section here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#instance

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Let me try that!

Comment: @Kahlid It is still not working. Did you tested this policy in your case for any instance?

Comment: You're right. The `RunInstances` edit was not complete. I have updated the answer (after testing and verifying that it is working from my side).

Comment: See also my note on the `PassRole` permission. You might be interested in that as well.

Comment: @Kahlid I tried but same error "You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message".

Comment: In that case, can you share the exact command (with parameters) you're using? There are many factors to consider.

Comment: I have edited my question as "Edited on 23rd January (To Show what exactly I have done)". Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: I have just repeated the exact steps you have (using both; the AWS Management Console and the CLI) and I was able to start and stop the instance. Perhaps you have a `Deny` rule somewhere that is overriding your `Allow` rules.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you specify multiple resources:

```
…
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/home/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/home/${aws:username}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Source:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html

**EDIT:**

You can also use Conditions if you want to filter out instead of including all the required resources manually.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried for S3 and it does work perfectly alright but my question is related to EC2 instance level permission.